# JavaFX, how can i bind dinamically created Increment and Decrement Buttons to manipulate a specific object?

Tags: java, javafx

I hope i will formulate this question the best i can.

I'm making a restaurant manager program for an university project using JavaFX and Springboot for my backend. Right now i'm facing a problem.

I'm implementing the 'take an order' functionality for waiters. The way it works is:

- When i load the TakeOrderView, the *initialize()* method uses the API REST to obtain from the server all the dishes.
- Then, i cycle through all the dishes to dinamically create TitledPanes, one for every dish, with dinamically created 'minus' and 'plus' buttons.

This is the code i used:

```
public void populateAccordion() {
 for (Dish dish : DishesList) {
                        TitledPane TPDish = new TitledPane();
                        TPDish.setText(dish.getDishName());

                        // Dishes


                        // Name
                        TextFlow dishName = new TextFlow();

                        Text boldText = new Text("Name: ");
                        boldText.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.BOLD, 14));
                        Text plainText = new Text(dish.getName());
                        plainText.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", 16));

                        dishName.getChildren().addAll(boldText, plainText);

                        // Same for cost, description and allergens. I'll not show it for the sake of brevity. It's the same as above.



                        // Here comes the tricky part
                        Button minus = new Button("-");
                        TextField quantity = new TextField("0");
                        Button plus = new Button("+");

                        quantity.getStyleClass().add("textfield");
                        quantity.setPrefWidth(30);
                        quantity.setPrefHeight(29);
                        minus.getStyleClass().add("circular-button");
                        plus.getStyleClass().add("circular-button");


                        minus.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                            @Override
                            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                                int value = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText());
                                if (value > 0) {
                                    quantity.setText(Integer.toString(value - 1));
                                    
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        plus.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                            @Override
                            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                                int value = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText());
                                quantity.setText(Integer.toString(value + 1));
                            }
                        });

                        HBox chooseQuantity = new HBox();
                        chooseQuantity.getChildren().addAll(minus, quantity, plus);
                        chooseQuantity.setSpacing(5);


                        VBox content = new VBox();
                        content.getChildren().addAll(dishName, dishCost, dishDescription, dishAllergens, chooseQuantity);

                        TPDish.setContent(content);
                        dishAccordion.getPanes().add(TPPiatto);
                    }
```

Thing is, this works, at least graphically. But i cannot use this code to manipulate an Order.

In fact, in my Controller (since i'm using an MVC pattern) i have an Order, which is a Map<Dish, Integer> to store the quantity. The behaviour i want is that when i press the 'plus' button in the "Pizza" TitledPane (for example) it "retrieves" the Dish, and calls a *updateOrder(dish, quantity)* method in the controller that should work in a similar way:

```
public void updateOrder(Dish dish, Integer quantity){
  order.put(dish, quantity);
}
```

But the way i stuctured my code, i don't have access to the Dish stored in its TitledPane, since they are dinamically created and after the for cycle ends, i no longer have access to the 'Dish' that "corresponds" to its titledpane. I don't know how could i implement this.

Also, the 'quantity' variable is just a graphic thing right now, its not binded to the Order. I'd like that when my 'Pizza' dish in the order has a quantity of 0, the quantity shown in the titledpane is 0, and when i press '+' 3 times, the quantity in the order gets incremented, thus incrementing the quantity in the titledpane.

Please remember i'm just a University student with little to no knowledge on the best way to solve this.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: It's not really clear what the problem is. Presumably the code you posted has a reference to the controller. The current `Dish` reference is in scope at the point you define the handlers for the buttons. Why not just call `controller.updateOrder(dish, value);` directly in the two `handle(...)` methods? If that's not possible for some reason, create and post a [mre] as suggested.

Comment: You're right, my problem was that the way i was structuring my code it wasn't working, and i thought that since that handle was placed inside a for cycle, when the method ended it could not distinguish between different dishes. Now it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the way I structured my code, I don't have access to the `Dish`

This is not true. You have a perfectly valid reference to the current `Dish` defined in the `for` loop. You can simply call the method in the handler, using that reference:

```
for (Dish dish : DishesList) {

    // ...                    

    minus.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            int value = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText());
            if (value > 0) {
                quantity.setText(Integer.toString(value - 1));

                updateOrder(dish, value);

            }
        }
    });

    plus.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            int value = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText());
            quantity.setText(Integer.toString(value + 1));

            updateOrder(dish, value);

        }
    });
}
```